# Detect cattle on high resolution satellite images

Tags: remote-sensing

I have no deep experience in remote sensing. I would like to know if it might be feasible to detect cattle (i.e. a single cow or bull) from a high resolution satellite image e.g. Worldview 3  with a spatial resolution of 0.31m. I was thinking about visual interpretation. Big animals have a diameter of about 1.80 meters and their colour (white brown) is clearly distinguishable from the ground below (green).

The aim is just to be able to identify if there is one or more animals (generally the herd is bigger than just a single animal).

This question is rather speculative since I don't think anybody has probably done anything similar before but maybe you could indicate if you think I should give it a try with a sample image...

Comment: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0085239#pone-0085239-g001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some studies and pilot projects about this kind of cattle detection:
Please see the links:
https://www.itc.nl/library/papers_2012/msc/nrm/zhengyang.pdf

http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0085239#pone-0085239-g001

so the answer is yes, it's feasable to detect.